# REST Assured - org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: <server_address>:80 failed to respond

Tags: java, rest, http, rest-assured

I'm facing this issue with REST Assured 3.0.3 intermittently, and the corresponding line of code is in a for loop.

It is a simple GET call like mentioned below:

```
response = given().setBaseUri(someBaseUri).setBasePath(someEndPoint).param("key", "value").header("X-Authorization-Token", my_auth_token).get();
```

I found a couple of StackOverflow answers suggesting to resolve the issue using `ConnectionConfig`, but I don't know how to resolve the issue while using REST Assured.

Below is the full trace:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: <full_server_address> failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2122)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:451)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1525)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor152.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:815)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:815)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1725)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:815)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1731)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:815)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:168)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:815)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:252)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
```

Please help.

Comment: Random guess. But try putting a wait in between each call. Basically slow the whole thing down. If you are looping the calls and hitting it too fast it could be causing issues if whatever you are hitting can only handle a very small load. This feels a little unlikely but still possible without knowing any information about what you are testing against.

Comment: Thanks @canpan14 for your response. I think I've figured out the solution here. I've added these lines in my code `ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig(); connectionConfig.closeIdleConnectionsAfterEachResponse();`, but since the issue is intermittent, I need to observe if this solution really helps. This `ConnectionConfig` is from REST Assured. I'll post this as an answer if I do not face the `NoHttpResponseException` with this solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding this code seems to have resolved the issue. I haven't faced the issue even with the slower staging test servers.

```
Response response = given()...get();
ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig();
connectionConfig.closeIdleConnectionsAfterEachResponse();
```

What I did not understand though is, how is the `ConnectionConfig` object working with `Response` object for this.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you gave the code for the whole request to show where `ConnectionConfig` was actually used i.e `response = given() . . . .`

Comment: Could you please confirm where to include this change ? i tried just adding these lines after rest assured given() and facing same issue only for POST call. Kindly help

Comment: My bad. Apologies for missing this out in the details in my answer. For me, adding this snippet after the `RestAssured` get() had helped. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But i still face the issue :(

Comment: Ah, ok. I somehow feel that the answer I have provided is not an elegant solution. This issue probably needs to be dug deeper to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand RestAssured http connection making mechanism, with each new object of RestAssuredConfig it creates new httpclient connection with server. For few of the API call it is possible that the response is received in form of Chunks, in such cases may be intermittently server closed the connection and client is unware of it due to this the connection is in stale state and NoHttpResponse error is thrown.
To handle this intermittent issue best way to have some retry mechanism to create new http connection and close the previous for which NoHttpResponseException occurs.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer - can you please format your answer better to help others? Adding some code or links for your "retry mechanism" would be great as well 

Answer (score 0):

Better code example:

```
given().config(RestAssuredConfig.config().connectionConfig(
    ConnectionConfig.connectionConfig().closeIdleConnectionsAfterEachResponse()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in Apache Http Client 5.0

```
org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8443 failed to respond
```

Solve the problem closing idle connections in PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
cm.closeIdle(TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(10));
```