# Rest Assured POST call throws org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java, rest, api, automated-tests, rest-assured

Rest Assured POST call throws org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException : failed to respond. Same url is working with GET call but only the POST call throws below error. i have tried with

- RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames());
- Setting proxy configurations
- Steps in
  [REST Assured - org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: <server_address>:80 failed to respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159462/rest-assured-org-apache-http-nohttpresponseexception-server-address80-fail)

  but still issue is not solved.

> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException servername:port failed to respond
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)

```
        RestAssured.baseURI = url;
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().log().all();
        RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames());

        request.formParams(params);
        request.headers(headers);
        request.body(body);
        Response resp = request.post();
        System.out.println("Response data is =>  " + resp.asString());
```

Log message from rest assured:

```
        Request method: POST
        Request URI:    https://testurl.com/atRegId
        Proxy:          <none>
        Request params: <none>
        Query params:   <none>
        Form params:    <none>
        Path params:    <none>
        Headers:        Authorization=Bearer sdweqweweqwewe
        Accept=*/*
        Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
        Cookies:        <none>
        Multiparts:     <none>
        Body:
        {"id": "4KJ34K324K3K4K3K","response": "json data"}"
```

Comment: Which rest assured version?

Comment: You have mentioned that its working with `GET`, have you checked the endpoint with `POST` may be it doesn't support `POST`?

Comment: Yes, endpoint is working fine and supports POST. Actually the post operation is performed in server side only the response is not recived via rest assured. And i have tested the call with jmeter where it works fine. Using version 3.0.6

Comment: Please post your rest assured code

Comment: Updated the code used and sample logger from rest assured

Comment: Add "Connection : close" in your header

Comment: Yes tried with "Connection : close" in header, no change in reported issue.

Comment: When you say it is working fine with a GET; did you try it with the http**s** URI?